# Accessing variables from other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

While using HTML with JS, I can load my files and variables in the global scope are accessible everywhere. But what to do, when there is no HTML, just plain JS?

I have a file called `bot.js` with this code:

```
// other stuff..

client.login(token); // bot token
```

Next to this file I have a folder with a file in it called `commonResources.js` with this code:

```
// other stuff..

var token = "myToken";
```

The application says "token is not defined". How can I access it?

Comment: Are this files front-end js or nodeJS?

Comment: I use nodeJs for my Discord Bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering this files are back-end files (nodeJS) this is the correct way to do it. At the bottom of the file that has the variable you require you will type this command to execute the second file:

```
require('./bot.js')(token);
```

After that you will go to the file that you need to use token and type this at the top:

```
module.exports = function (token) {
//use your token
}
```